# fill in the 2 tables below using the Employee USer Statuses table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I basically have to fill in the 2 tables below using the Employee USer Statuses table. If you could just point me in the right direction for the two tables I need to solve for that would extremely helpful. Thank you in advance. I just want to learn how to do this but need a direction!

Question 1)

```
   Team  | # of Users 
 --------|------------ 
  Team A |            
  Team B |            
  Team C |            
  Team D |            
  Team E |            
  Team F |
```

Question 2)

```
   Team  | # of Manual Users | Avg. Data Health of Team's Manual Users 
 --------|-------------------|----------------------------------------- 
  Team A |                   |                                         
  Team B |                   |                                         
  Team C |                   |                                         
  Team D |                   |                                         
  Team E |                   |                                         
  Team F |                   |
```

Employee User Statuses

```
  Employee |  Team  | Capture mode | User state | Data Health 
 ----------|--------|--------------|------------|------------- 
         1 | Team A |              | link_sent  | --          
         2 | Team A |              | link_sent  | --          
         3 | Team A | Mobile       | active     | 0%          
         4 | Team A | Mobile       | active     | 96%         
         5 | Team F | Mobile       | active     | 12%         
         6 | Team F | Mobile       | active     | --          
         7 | Team F | Mobile       | active     | --          
         8 | Team F |              | link_sent  | 7%          
         9 | Team F |              | link_sent  | --          
        10 | Team F |              | link_sent  | --          
        11 | Team F |              | link_sent  | --          
        12 | Team F |              | link_sent  | --          
        13 | Team F | Mobile       | active     | 1%          
        14 | Team F |              | link_sent  | --          
        15 | Team F | Manual       | active     | 0%
```

There are a lot more rows in Employee User Statuses but that's essentially the gist of it. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the countif() function for question 1. For question 2, try the countifs() function for the number of manual users per team; use averageifs() for the avg. data health.

Answer (score 0):

Make a pivot table of Employee User Statuses. Then:

```
Rows -> Team
Values -> Count of Employee
```

For the second one, add:

```
Values -> Average of Data Health
Filter -> Capture mode = Manual
```

Pivot tables are great, and they're pretty easy to explore and experiment with, go grab more tables and play around if you want to learn how to use them. But it's possible to generate meaningless or incorrect reports, so check own logic and pivot results and make sure it says what you think it should. Some of the more complex filtering and summation doesn't always work, as expected or at all. Uniformity and formatting of source data is another gotcha to look out for.

Comment: The disadvantages you mention are why I go for the formula each time... and cross-check...